# Whats the fastest way to find biggest sum of M adjacent elements in a matrix

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix

Suppose I have a square matrix of dimension N (N <= 50) and the adjacent elements do not include the diagonals.

How can I find the biggest sum between M adjacent elements, given M?

For example, take this matrix 4x4:

```
Matrix:           For M = 3           For M = 4

3 1 5 2           3  1  5  2          3  1  5 2
2 6 1 3           2 [6] 1  3          2 [6] 1 3
1 4 4 2           1 [4][4] 2          1 [4] 4 2
5 3 2 7           5  3  2  7         [5][3] 2 7

                  Biggest = 14        Biggest = 18
```

I tried to do this way, but after a certain dimension, it is very slow.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int mat[51][51];
int mark[51][51];
int m, n;
int biggest;

void search(int row, int column, int sum, int steps){
    if(row < 0 || row >= n || column < 0 || column >= n || mark[row][column]) {
        return;
    }

    sum += mat[row][column];

    mark[row][column] = 1;

    if(steps == m){

        if(biggest < sum) biggest = sum;

    }

    else{

        search(row - 1, column, sum, steps+1);
        search(row + 1, column, sum, steps+1);
        search(row, column + 1, sum, steps+1);
        search(row, column - 1, sum, steps+1);
    }

    mark[row][column] = 0;
}


int main(){

    memset(mat, 0, sizeof(mat));
    memset(mark, 0, sizeof(mark));

    biggest = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    scanf("%d", &m);

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]);
        }
    }


    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            search(i, j, 0, 1);
        }
    }


    printf("%d", biggest);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: How large is M? M <= 50?

Comment: That is a backtracking algorithm to solve the problem, isn't it?

Comment: If M==5, would a set of five numbers arranged in a "+" shape be acceptable? As far as I can tell, your current program does not permit such a shape, as it can't be created by horizontal and vertical movements without re-visiting a matrix element.

Comment: M <= 100, N <= 50
my solution is a backtracking algorithm...
yeah you are right... it is possible, and my program probably doesn't do it yet... but my problem is with time, I think my approach to solve this problem is wrong, cos it takes too long for big N

Comment: You tagged as C++ but although valid C++, it looks very much like "C-style" (use of C I/O, no use of std:: algorithms neither std:: containers, ...) Maybe retag to C ?

Comment: Is this from a programming contest?  If so, which one?

Comment: @EvgenyKluev the dp formulation in the link you mentioned counts higher-valued cells more than once (which actually does not solve either this or that question, see my comments there) - do you know of a way to reformulate that kind of dp to count cells only once per shape?

Answer (score 3):

**<sub>This answer does not include code (yet) and will later be extended with an implementation of the described algorithm</sub>**

The main difficulty is that certain "shapes" are processed many times. Consider a selection that is a filled rectangle. It can start from any cell and traverse in multiple different ways ("recursive paths") to reach the same selection (and obviously the same calculation). It is this issue that needs to be tackled.

To do that, you need to precompute the various shapes that can be selected for the given ***M***, then iterate the matrix and for each cell (serving as the top-left of the shape) calculate and compare the sum for all shape selections.

<strike>The precomputation is done by using a recursive function just like in the question that "paints" a *(2M-1)<sup>2</sup>* matrix with the cells in the path, starting in the middle. In the end condition (M cells selected), the generated shape is compared to existing shapes in the accumulating "shapes list", and only added if it's not already there.</strike> **need to solve for "+" shape scenario**.

Optimizations should be used in the precompute stage to avoid " transferring" the problem from the computation to the precomputation stage for very large *M*s, for example, limit traversals such that it is illegal to go above the starting row (and as a result, the shape matrix only needs to be *M(2M-1)* big).

Comment: Isn't this still quite expensive for large M?  For example, [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A001168) shows that there are about 20 thousand billion polyominoes with 25 connected cells (and this number roughly quadruples for each increase of 1 in M)

Comment: @PeterdeRivazw - That's great info, and raises an interesting question about the feasibility of my algorithm, but since I'm addressing (and solving) a major flaw in the naive algorithm that suffers from the same problem, but exponentially, I guess it's just too much work. Let's see if anyone comes up with a valid algorithm that manages to do better (I really don't see how though.. You have to iterate through all options even if you do very little work each time)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an elementary depth-first-search in Python, using sets to hash the shapes (it's a revision of my answer here, [Maximum sum of k connected elements of a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32824002/maximum-sum-of-k-connected-elements-of-a-matrix/32833139#32833139)). It seems to me that a DFS ought to keep the stack size on the order of `O(m)` (although the search space is still huge).

```py
from sets import Set

def f(a,m):
  stack = []
  hash = Set([])
  best = (0,[]) # sum, shape
  n = len(a)

  for y in range(n):
    for x in range(n):
      stack.append((a[y][x],Set([(y,x)]),1))

  while len(stack) > 0:
    s,shape,l = stack.pop()

    key = str(sorted(list(shape)))

    if l == m and key not in hash:
      hash.add(key)
      if s > best[0]:
        best = (s,shape)
    elif key not in hash:
      hash.add(key)
      for (y,x) in shape:
        if y < n - 1 and (y + 1,x) not in shape:
          copy = Set(shape)
          copy.add((y + 1,x))
          stack.append((s + a[y + 1][x],copy,l + 1))
        if y > 0 and (y - 1,x) not in shape:
          copy = Set(shape)
          copy.add((y - 1,x))
          stack.append((s + a[y - 1][x],copy,l + 1))
        if x < n - 1 and (y,x + 1) not in shape:
          copy = Set(shape)
          copy.add((y,x + 1))
          stack.append((s + a[y][x + 1],copy,l + 1))
        if x > 0 and (y,x - 1) not in shape:
          copy = Set(shape)
          copy.add((y,x - 1))
          stack.append((s + a[y][x - 1],copy,l + 1))

  print best
  print len(hash)
```

Output:

```py
matrix = [[3, 1, 5, 2,]           
         ,[2, 6, 1, 3,]        
         ,[1, 4, 4, 2]
         ,[5, 3, 2, 7]]

f(matrix,4) 
"""
(18, Set([(3, 1), (3, 0), (2, 1), (1, 1)]))
205 hash length
"""
```

Comment: When you find that the exact same question's been asked before, the thing to do is flag as a duplicate.